# Javascript Regex for DD/MM only

Tags: javascript, regex

I have looked all over stack overflow and tried making and changing regex's to suit my needs but do to my very limited understanding of them I am coming unstuck...

I need to make a Javascript regular expression to check DD/MM. I can get DD/MM/YYYY working but this is not what I need.

What I have is `^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$`. This checks for DD/MM/YYYY but I when I try to simply truncate the end I get errors. I know limited knowledge read about regex's in javascript...Links appreciated.

Comment: Show what you tried and explain what errors you saw. Also it looks like you want to recognize single digit days and months?

Comment: Actually, just checking `DD/MM` alone is not sufficient to determine if it be valid.  The reason is that February may have 28 _or_ 29 days, depending on the year.  You need to know the year to make your assertion.

Comment: I understand that TIm I will be making a function to check it if it passes the regex...I just dont have a very good grasp on regular expressions

Comment: remove "(\/)\d{4}$" from your regex and check

Comment: Try this: ^[0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}$ here - https://regex101.com/r/2CXAky/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited - simplified version as mentioned in the comments below**

Based on your regex, this would be what you are looking for:

```
^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[0-9]|1[0-2])$
```

But as Tim has pointed out in the comments, it is not bullet proof to do it that way.

You can look at the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/oQ2k6v/1
regex101 is a very nice site for regexes. It explains every part of the regex.

Comment: Thank you, thats perfect. I will be making a function that checks for valid date input legend. I have marked as correct

Comment: Removing the unnecessary parentheses you'll get `^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[0-9]|1[0-2])$`

Comment: This is matching `00/00`, not sure it's a valid date!

Comment: Hi Toto, I am checking date validation with a function. The regex was to make sure the data is coming in, in the right format...Thanks for the bug find though!

Comment: @PaulHashmi: then `^\d\d\/\d\d$` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid matching dates like `00/00`, use:

```
^(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O9ffu5/1)

According to comment, you said " I will be making a function to check it if it passes the regex.", So it's enough to use simpler regex:

```
^\d\d\/\d\d$
```

Comment: @tripleee: Sure, but you can't validate a date without year for example `29/02` on leap year. OP add a comment after my post that they call a validation function.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/
```

Comment: This is matching `00/01`

Comment: @Toto Okay, it was fixed

Comment: Sorry, but now it doesn't match `15/05`

Comment: @Toto Okay, it was inattention